# what size lumber for a 8' horizontal span to hold a 250 lb. load

Tags: load-bearing

to hang a sky chair on patio. Will be supporting at ends of 4x4 or some laminates of 2x4 (space limits), overall length is 90", max weight of chair and person 250 lbs. What size is suggested?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Are you expecting the occupant to swing, and if so how enthusiastically?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on 1) Species, 2) Grade, and 3) Condition of use (wet location, etc.)

1) Some species of wood are stronger than others, (i.e.: Douglas Fir-Larch is much stronger than pine,)

2) Some grades of wood can be 80% more than others.

3) Wood, pressure treated, can loose 20% of its strength and if it’s installed outside in a rainy or high humidity climate, can loose an additional 15% of its strength.

So, for your chair outside with 7’-6” span, I’d recommend 2-2x6 of “Select grade or better” or 1-2x8 of “number 1 grade or better”.

Answer (score 1):

My rule of thumb for simple loads is, no more than 4' span, use a 2X4, up to 6' span, use a 2X6, and up to a 8' span, use a 2X8, which is what I would recommend in your case. It is overkill for your case, but I rather oversize than have it fail on you. Fastening it has yet to be dealt with consideration of your availability of hardware and carpentry talents.